# To verify that a sequence of functions is increasing

Tags: calculus

How do I verify that $f_n(x)=1_{[0,n]}(x)e^{-x}$ is increasing? I know I have to verify that $x_1<x_2$ implies $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$. Should I take $x_1<n<x_2<n+1$?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The task is to show $f_n \leqslant f_{n+1}$. Each individual $f_n$ is monotonically decreasing on $x \geqslant 0$.

Comment: No, that is a statement that $f$ is an increasing function. You need to show that the sequence is increasing, not the function. I.e. $n_1<n_2 \implies \forall x. f_{n_1}(x) \leq f_{n_2}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible senses in which the term "increasing" could be understood here, and I think you've chosen the wrong one. The first is to say that each individual function is increasing (fix an $n$ and you get an increasing function). That is not true: take $n=1$ and $f(.25)>f(.5)$.

The other (correct) way to intepret it is that the family of functions is increasing with $n$. So fix $x_0$, then $f_n(x_0)$ is an increasing sequence of numbers (more precisely, it is non-decreasing).

Comment: Ok, so to verify this, I take $x_1<n<x_2<n+1$. Therefore $f_n(x_1)=f_{n+1}(x_1)$ and $f_n(x_2)=0\leq f_{n+1}(x_2)$ since  $f_{n+1}(x_2)>0$. So in both cases $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$. Is my reasoning good?

Comment: No. You must show that for arbitrary $x_1$, $n_1 \leq n_2 \Rightarrow f_{n_1}(x_1) \leq f_{n_2}(x_1)$. You have no need of a second point $x_2.$

Comment: So how is it done

Comment: @Vaolter Pick a real number. If is is negative, $f_n(x)$ is zero for all $n$, so you have no problem. If it is positive, think about what happens as $n$ increases. What is  $f_n(x)$ for $x < n$? For $x>n$? For $x=n$? Why is it that $f_n(x)$ never decreases as $n$ gets bigger?

Comment: I understand what you saying, $f_n$ is just $e^{-x}$ when $x\leq n$, but I how should I put it in writing. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Vaolter Try to put it into writing, and I'll tell you if it could be improved. A good strategy is just to write it how you would explain it to someone.